# Xamarin Form chnage the value of Binding Data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin from.  I have the following:

```
 <Image Source="tv_off.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="The_name" HeightRequest="200" Opacity="{Binding Source={x:Reference sld1},Path=Value}">
        </Image>
```

and then the slider:

```
 <Slider x:Name="sld1"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"></Slider>
```

which is bind to the image tag.
I want to change the value of "Path=Value" in image tag, for instance half of the value of the slider. How can I accomplish this (beside using converter)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking something like the following should work:

```
<Image Source="tv_off.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="The_name" HeightRequest="200" 
       Opacity="{Binding ElementName=sld1, Path=Value}" >
</Image>
```

**Note:** Please note that the value for ***Opacity*** is 0.0 to 1.0 so the slider should have a Min of 0.0 and Max of 1.0

Comment: Ok sorry I have done similar in WPF and WinPhone 8/10 projects.  I have no actual experience in Xamarin and figured that would just carryover.  Do you get a xaml or build/compile error when trying what I suggested?  If you can actually run it perhaps bind a label to the slider's value so you can see what the current value is for debugging purposes.  Did you try to manually set the opacity to something like 0.25 to make sure it's just not he image?

Comment: Yes, I get the compiler error.  I actually tested on Emulator and the device but no luck. I hard coded the opacity value and it works fine tho.